# Update stored information in Python

Tags: python, linux, lcd

I am working on a pi device that displays it's ip to an lcd screen. The code works on the most part. It repeats via an automated processes in linux (the cron daemon). This works well enough, however the ip information does not update when the script is repeated. I have looked here and online regarding how to clear the stored strings but I am stuck. Please could someone help.

here is the main part of the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import sys
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD

from Adafruit_CharLCD import Adafruit_CharLCD
from subprocess import *
from time import sleep, strftime
from datetime import datetime

cmd = "ip -4 addr show wlan0 | grep inet | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1"

cmd2 = "ip -4 addr show eth0 | grep inet | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1"

def run_cmd(cmd):
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    output = p.communicate()[0]
    return output

lcd_rs        = 25  
lcd_en        = 24
lcd_d4        = 23
lcd_d5        = 17
lcd_d6        = 18
lcd_d7        = 22
lcd_backlight = 4

lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows    = 2


lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCD(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7,
                       lcd_columns, lcd_rows, lcd_backlight)

# Display Wlan0 IP
time.sleep(2.0)
lcd.clear()
lcd.message('Wlan0')
time.sleep(2.0)

lcd.clear()
ipaddr = run_cmd(cmd)
lcd.message(datetime.now().strftime('%b %d  %H:%M:%S\n'))
lcd.message('IP %s' % (ipaddr))
sleep(2)

# Display Eth0 IP
time.sleep(2.0)
lcd.clear()
lcd.message('Eth0')
time.sleep(2.0)
lcd.clear()
ipaddr = run_cmd(cmd2)
lcd.message(datetime.now().strftime('%b %d  %H:%M:%S\n'))
lcd.message('IP %s' % (ipaddr))
sleep(2)
time.sleep(5.0)


lcd.clear()
lcd.blink(True)
lcd.message('Clearing\nCache')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(5.0)
```

Comment: Your script runs straight top to bottom. Every run is a new script instance. Or in other words: everything is reset on every run. What do you want to update?

Comment: That's what I thought. However, when cron repeats the script it keeps the same IP (cmd, cmd2) addresses even when they have been changed and/or disconnected.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your command pipes that retrieve the IP adresses.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a function which sends an information to your device. Additionally you need to create a function `get_cmd(interface)` to obtain an ip address for given interface. You request the same `cmd` twice and I suppose, you get information only for one interface.

```
import time
import sys
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD

from Adafruit_CharLCD import Adafruit_CharLCD
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from time import sleep, strftime
from datetime import datetime

cmd = "ip -4 addr show {interface} | grep inet | awk '{{print $2}}' | cut -d/ -f1"


def run_cmd(cmd):
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    output = p.communicate()[0]
    return output


def get_cmd(interface):
    return cmd.format(interface=interface)


def lcd_show(lcd, interface):
    cmd = get_cmd(interface)
    ipaddr = run_cmd(cmd)

    lcd.clear()
    lcd.message(interface)
    time.sleep(2)

    lcd.clear()
    lcd.message(datetime.now().strftime('%b %d  %H:%M:%S\n'))
    lcd.message('IP %s' % (ipaddr))
    time.sleep(2)


lcd_rs        = 25  
lcd_en        = 24
lcd_d4        = 23
lcd_d5        = 17
lcd_d6        = 18
lcd_d7        = 22
lcd_backlight = 4

lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows    = 2
lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCD(
    lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7,
    lcd_columns, lcd_rows, lcd_backlight)

time.sleep(2)
try:
    while True
        lcd_show(lcd, 'Wlan0')
        lcd_show(lcd, 'Eth0')
        sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.blink(True)
    lcd.message('Clearing\nCache')
```

Comment: Thank you I will try. I do get information for both interfaces with this code.

Comment: I have tested, it does not work. As def just produces a blank screen and the get command produces the same results as before.

Comment: I don't know what you tested. I've updated a program to show this example explained

Comment: Thank you for this. I have now got my code to work. It was a problem in Cron.